# Is it possible to scrape data from facebook using VBA?

Tags: vba, facebook, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am wondering if it is possible to VBA to scrape data from public facebook pages such as number of followers or number of likes. I put together the code below.

Right now I am assuming to face two issues: (i) internet explorer is not supported anymore by facebook and (ii) I am not sure if facebook allows scraping.

So, I guess what I am looking for is actually a code which a reads out the webpage's source code. To keep things simple: I would be happy to use internet explorer (i.e., skip problem (i)) and just read out the number of "others like this".

See attached screenshot for class name in DOM explorer and number of likes I am looking for.[Screenshot to illustrate target figure and DOM class name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOxIS.png)

Any ideas?

Code:

```
Sub social_facebook()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim url As String

url = "https://www.facebook.com/adidasoriginals"

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim results(0 To 4) ', counter As Long, i As Long
        With IE
            .Visible = True
        
                    .navigate url
                    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    Set html = IE.document
                    Set HTMLDivElement = html.getElementsByClassName("_59k _2rgt _1j-f _2rgt")
                    '_59k _2rgt _1j-f _2rgt >> this is - according to my understanding - the class name I am looking for.
                    Debug.Print HTMLDivElement.innerHTML
               
            .Quit
        End With

    End With

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------

End Sub
```

Comment: 2) You are correct Facebook does not allow scraping.

Answer (score 0):

HTMLDivElement is a collection. You need to get first item :

```
Set html = IE.document
Set HTMLDivElement = html.getElementsByClassName("_59k _2rgt _1j-f _2rgt")
'_59k _2rgt _1j-f _2rgt >> this is - according to my understanding - the class name I am looking for.
Debug.Print HTMLDivElement(0).innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName` method of `Document` interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s). The element you want is the fifth element of class `_59k _2rgt _1j-f _2rgt`, so the code is like this:

```
Set html = IE.document
Set HTMLDivElement = html.getElementsByClassName("_59k _2rgt _1j-f _2rgt")(4)
Debug.Print HTMLDivElement.innerHTML
```